# Should I consider rate limiting my REST APIs?

Tags: api, rest, rate-limiting

I am in the process of creating a product where users can use both a mobile app and browser. The APIs are exposed as REST calls. As of now these REST APIs will not be called by any third party.

Should I consider rate limiting API calls?

Comment: If no third parties are hitting the API, are you concerned you will abuse it?

Comment: @Madness, I was thinking more on the lines of rate limiting for security.

Comment: @coder007 yes for security also.  you can also rate limit per IP (or network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes.  There are libraries out there for doing it.  But if the question is just whether or not it should be done, then IMHO yes.

I have done this for personal projects and for previous employer, its not that hard.  Just yesterday a friend told me how he inadvertently brought down a 3rd party service his employer was using.  He made his company's services faster which lead to more requests to the 3rd party service and brought it down. So his web services were rate limiting the 3rd party service by being slow.  If the 3rd party service had rate limiting this would have been avoided.

Rate limiting is important to protect downstream resources, like DB's.  If you do not protect these resources you might run into an unrecoverable outage due to a spike in traffic.

Its important that you prioritize the development and deployment of this compared to the other things your new product will require... e.g. might not be needed for versions 0.x.

Comment: Thanks. Makes much more sense now.